# How to force automatically change the parental block height when inside of this block the position absolute block exists which getting content?

Tags: html, css

I have the parent's block (red) that should change its size by height relatively the content filling inside the green block.

The green block has an absolute position, and this is a must.

The question is about the content filling of the green block and the logical automatical size changing of the red block.

So, 2 question:

1. How to center the green block by the horizontal/center?
2. How to automatically change the red block's height relatively the content filling of the green block?

```
<body>
<div class="some"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>
    <div class="content">Content</div>   
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
body {
  background: purple;
}

.some {
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  width: 1030px;
  height: 600px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.main {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  margin-top: -50px;
  width: 400px;
}

.content {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px auto; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xtupmyvf/2/

Comment: can you upvote when you are privileged

Comment: yes, I will do, not only once, you saved my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample solution here https://jsfiddle.net/saksham_malhotra/upnrfjm0/

There is a lot going on in your code which is unnecessary and I have written a simplified version of it. The crux is to take care of the `display` properties to get a good layout.

You need not make the left section `absolute` positioned to stick it to the left. Just make the wrapping container `display: block` to not to take the whole width.